# How to get rid of scroll bars/arrows in Wordpress, when using font style called 'Pre'

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

When on Wordpress I use font `Pre`, instead of seamlessly showing up formatted as Fixed space font, which I was going for, I get

- fixed space font
- inside rectangular space area, colored in gray color to accentuate itself
- it has horizontal and vertical scroll bars on right and bottom, with arrows.

Those arrows look ugly and distract from the overall placement.  moreover, there is nothing to scroll, so the arrows and scroll bars are meaningless.

**Question:**

How can I get rid of those scroll bars and arrows, while keeping fixed font styling?  I have WordPress 4.1 with default theme, Twenty Fifteen.

**More on "Pre":**

For clarity, I do not mean HTML's `<pre>` tag.  I mean the WP's Font Style called  **Pre**.  Upon examination, that font does insert HTML tags `<pre>` around the "Pre"-styled text block, but I am guessing it is the CSS styling or possibly the WP's Theme that causes those arrows and scroll bars to show up.

Comment: Do you mean the <pre> tag?

Comment: No.  In WP Admin's "Edit Post" section, there is a "ribbon" with text formatting tools.  There is one that says "Paragraph" and allows you to change the level of text heading from `Heading 1` to `Heading 6`.  It also has an option called `Pre`.  I assumed it does fixed space font, which it does, but using it yields the above problem, when viewing the post in "user mode".

Comment: Heading 1 is just human for `<h1>` tag, the same way Pre is just human for `<pre>` - see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre - It may not be what you're thinking it is. Aside that, just inspect element and play with the css. That's how you adjust it if you really want to, but I would say just use anything that's not pre since it is likely styled that way for a reason

Comment: that inserts a <pre> tag I would guess. Click the `Text(HTML)`  in the top right of the text editor to see if there are `<pre>` tags.

Comment: Yes, that text gets surrounded by simple `<pre>` tags.
Also, the parent container uses a class called `entry-content`.  Looking at CSS I do not see anything that will cause those scroll bars, but I am guessing this is Theme-dependent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the sound of it you need to use the CSS `overflow` property. You would add this to your theme's `style.css` file.

```
pre {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

**Note:** If that doesn't work let me know and adjust it accordingly based on the article below.

**See:** http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp